# Appropriate method to Predict Power and time in this set

Tags: predictive-models, prediction, statistical-power

I am unsure what method to search for and most appropriate approach to solving the predictions of the missing **?** values in the below data.

Can you demonstrate the best methodology to determine the predicted values?

```
[![Dependant    weight(kg)  distance(metres)    time(seconds)   time600 Speed 1 ms  Speed 2 ms  Force   Work Done 1     Work Done 2 Total Work  Power 1 Power 2 Average Power
1   59  1200    70.38   35.8    17.35   16.76   6.020408163 3612.244898 3612.244898 7224.489796 104.4605234 100.9006955 102.6806094
2   58  1200    69.95   34.9    17.12   17.19   5.918367347 3551.020408 3551.020408 7102.040816 101.3129931 101.7484358 101.5307144
3   57  1400    83.15   34.8    16.55   17.24   5.816326531 4653.061224 3489.795918 8142.857143 96.23704704 100.2814919 98.25926947
4   56  1600    95.2    35.4    16.72   16.95   5.714285714 5714.285714 3428.571429 9142.857143 95.5566173  96.85230024 96.20445877
5   58  1400    ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?][1]][1]
```

[image]

Comment: Don't you want to add any background information? This looks like 4 time steps and you need a forecast for the 5th. This is really a small sample.

Comment: Thanks Richard the sample is small so its hopefully easier to demonstrate. Is there any background information that would be useful?

Comment: All background info would be useful How does weight play together with distance? And the small sample is not good: it is bad .. not speaking in statistical terms: how can we find a pattern if we just see that few examples?

Comment: First, it's probably just semantics, but there are a lot of ways to predict datapoints (in a timeseries or not) and as long as we do not know the true values of the '?' datapoints, there is no way of finding the best way of predicting these missings (i.e. the method which most closely predicts the true values). Second, do you want to predict all other values for dependant 58 at 1400meters (whatever those represent) or is this missing data in your dataset?

Comment: Well i had figured if i was able to predict the power then this would allow me to backwards solve other missing data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a linear model to infer data. In R, this would be:

```
x <- c(1200,1200,1400,1600,1400) # Taking the distance metric from your example
w <- c(70.38,69.95,83.15,95.2,NA) # Taking the weight metrics from your example
```

Note that in R, missing data are represented as `NA`.

```
model <- lm(w~x) # Define a linear model of x against w
pred <- predict(model,newdata=as.data.frame(x)) # Create a predicted w value for all x values in the data
```

Note that because you have a prediction for all of the dependent data, whether it is missing or not, you can estimate how accurate the inferred data are.

Comment: If i just use distance and time i dont include weight or other factors. Would this work similarly for power ?

Comment: @sayth: exactly the same principles for predicting, say power, are applicable.